# How to fix error " No such file or directory error" with vue-cli create

Tags: vue.js, vue-cli-3

I installed vue-cli 3. I tried creating a vue app with vue create but I get a no such file error.

```
~$ vue create hello-world
bash: /usr/local/bin/vue: No such file or directory
```

Installing vue/cli3

```
yarn global v0.15.1
warning No license field
[1/4] Resolving packages...
[2/4] Fetching packages...
warning fsevents@1.2.9: The platform "linux" is incompatible with this module.
info "fsevents@1.2.9" is an optional dependency and failed compatibility check. Excluding it from installation.
[3/4] Linking dependencies...
[4/4] Building fresh packages...
success Installed @vue/cli@3.12.0 with binaries:
      - vue
Done in 1.69s.
```

Comment: _"I installed vue-cli 3"_  doesn't sound like it worked. How did you install it?

Comment: Did you install vue-cli 3 global? `npm install -g @vue/cli`

Comment: yes I did install vue-cli 3

Answer (score 18, accepted):

I hope this helps somebody but the same happened to me, I just had to restart the terminal before attempting to use it. I mean, after install vue-cli with `npm i -g @vue/cli` restart the terminal or update the source with something like: `source ~/.bash_profile` (or just restart the terminal, is easier) so the path in your profile gets updated :). That fixed it for me.

Answer (score 1):

After installing vue-cli with npm i -g @vue/cli and update the source with something like **source ~/.profile** **or (~/.bash_profile)**. That worked for me.

Answer (score 1):

I just solved this error by simply adding `sudo` like `sudo npm update -g @vue/cli` #OR `sudo yarn global upgrade --latest @vue/cli`

Answer (score 0):

***For anyone comming in here 3 years later like I,***

From the [Vue CLI installation page](https://cli.vuejs.org/guide/installation.html) as of March 2023, there is a message at the top of the page saying

> ⚠️ Vue CLI is in Maintenance Mode!
>
> > For new projects, it is now recommended to `use create-vue` to scaffold Vite-based projects. Also refer to the Vue 3 Tooling Guide for the latest recommendations.
> > I did that and followed the prompts to create my first Vue project.