# vue cmd not working in Git-Bash, but does in PowerShell

Tags: vue.js, git-bash

If I run vue --version in my Terminus bash, I get:

```
$ vue -v
/bin/sh: /Users/kirkb/AppData/Local/Yarn/bin/../Data/global/node_modules/.bin/vue: No such file or directory
```

If I do it in PowerShell I get:

```
PS C:\WINDOWS\system32> vue --version
@vue/cli 4.5.13
```

**Any way to get it working in Git-Bash?**

Answer (score 0):

Check your `$PATH` first in your git bash session.

As [seen here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66333468/6309), there might be a step missing in your current shell.

The alternative is to install it through `npm` in a WSL2 full-fledge Linux machine in your Windows 10 session.