# npm install -g @vue/cli but INSTALL ERROR

Tags: vue.js

This is my environment..

- MacOs Big Sur version 11.2.3
- npm version 7.15.1
- node version version 16.3.0

Below is my error..

```
npm WARN deprecated @hapi/topo@3.1.6: This version has been deprecated and is no longer supported or maintained
npm WARN deprecated @hapi/bourne@1.3.2: This version has been deprecated and is no longer supported or maintained
npm WARN deprecated urix@0.1.0: Please see https://github.com/lydell/urix#deprecated
npm WARN deprecated har-validator@5.1.5: this library is no longer supported
npm WARN deprecated resolve-url@0.2.1: https://github.com/lydell/resolve-url#deprecated
npm WARN deprecated @hapi/address@2.1.4: Moved to 'npm install @sideway/address'
npm WARN deprecated uuid@3.4.0: Please upgrade  to version 7 or higher.  Older versions may use Math.random() in certain circumstances, which is known to be problematic.  See https://v8.dev/blog/math-random for details.
npm WARN deprecated uuid@3.4.0: Please upgrade  to version 7 or higher.  Older versions may use Math.random() in certain circumstances, which is known to be problematic.  See https://v8.dev/blog/math-random for details.
npm WARN deprecated request@2.88.2: request has been deprecated, see https://github.com/request/request/issues/3142
npm WARN deprecated @hapi/hoek@8.5.1: This version has been deprecated and is no longer supported or maintained
npm WARN deprecated @hapi/joi@15.1.1: Switch to 'npm install joi'

changed 943 packages, and audited 944 packages in 16s

59 packages are looking for funding
  run `npm fund` for details

13 vulnerabilities (3 moderate, 10 high)

Some issues need review, and may require choosing
a different dependency.

Run `npm audit` for details.
```

I try again and again.. but it's not work.
Please help me!!

Answer (score 1):

We miss a few infos here; you say that you get an install error, but these are just warnings about deprecated dependencies. Moreover, these dependencies doens’t look much related to @vue/cli itself…

Are these globally installed dependencies? You might wanna use [npm-check](https://www.npmjs.com/package/npm-check) and use it globally to see if these are old global dependencies that you should get uptodate (or get rid of):

```
$ npm-check -ug
```

Comment: I try to npm-check -ug.. but it's not work. 
so i install ```npm install -g npm-check``` but error message open

```npm WARN deprecated cross-spawn-async@2.2.5: cross-spawn no longer requires a build toolchain, use it instead
npm WARN deprecated core-js@2.6.12: core-js@<3.3 is no longer maintained and not recommended for usage due to the number of issues. Because of the V8 engine whims, feature detection in old core-js versions could cause a slowdown up to 100x even if nothing is polyfilled. Please, upgrade your dependencies to the actual version of core-js.```

Comment: It's not an error either, it's still a warning. `npm-check` should be installed anyway now, so try the command again and see if it does anything?

Comment: I'll do ```npm-check -ug```
but print error message ```zsh: command not found: npm-check```

Comment: Well, I can't say much here then… If you type `@vue/cli --version`, does anything shows up?

Comment: error looks like this.. ```zsh: no such file or directory: @vue/cli```

Comment: Maybe take a look at this, it might help: https://stackoverflow.com/a/61274658/4231598

Comment: Thank you for your help!
 i solve my problem

my solution code
```mkdir ~/.npm-global 
npm config set prefix '~/.npm-global' 

vi ~/.profile```
and add below code profile file
```export PATH=~/.npm-global/bin:$PATH```
after :wq
```source ~/.profile```

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

I have resolved in this method:

1. npm uninstall –g @ionic/cli
2. install nodejs
3. Reinstall again: npm install –g @ionic/cli

Answer (score 0):

**For Mac users**

First, Uninstall angular/cli: `sudo npm uninstall -g @angular/cli`

Then, go to **https://www.brew.sh/** and copy the link below **Install Homebrew** and paste it to the terminal and hit enter.

Then, type: `brew install angular-cli` and hit enter.

Finally, check the version: `ng --version`